# Supremum over all simple closed curves of integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This is a question from an old qualifying exam at my university. I expect there's some trick but I couldn't spot it.

The question is to find the supremum over all simple closed curves $C$ of $$\int_C (y^3 - y) \  dx - 2x^3 dy$$ and then determine if the supremum is actually obtained or not.

I thought that perhaps if this integral was actually independent of path, then it would follow that over simple closed curves, this integral would always be $0$ and that would make the supremum easy - just $0$. But this isn't true, as just integrating around the regular unit circle gives $-5\pi/4$.

My next thought was maybe Green's Theorem. I can write this as $$\int_{S_C} (-6x^2 - 3y^2 + 1) \  dx \ dy$$ where $S_C$ is the interior of the simple closed curve $C$ Then by linearity of the integral it appears that there is a term which just keeps track of the area of the region, which I can make as large as I like. I don't know how the other terms might effect things in this situation though, and if the supremum isn't infinity, I don't know if I'm any closer to working it out like this than I was the first way.

All the problems on the exam are straight forward, and none require any particularly high powered weaponry. So probably there is an easy way to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there a maximal region where $-6x^2-3y^2+1$ is positive?

Comment: @MichaelLee That would be the question I suppose, but I guess that's what I'm not sure how to work out. Are you trying to imply I should be able to see it easily from this? If so I'll take another crack at it.

Comment: Answer: Yes, and it's bounded by the closed curve $6x^2+3y^2 = 1$, which is an ellipse.

Comment: I think I see. The region should be some kind of ellipse. Works out since both terms are squares. I think maybe I thought one of them was a cube or something when taking the practice test - tripped myself.

Comment: Consider the fact that an integral can be split up over multiple regions (i.e. $\int_{\Omega} f\,\mathrm{d}m = \int_{\Omega'} f\,\mathrm{d}m+\int_{\Omega\setminus\Omega'} f\,\mathrm{d}m$, where $\Omega'\subset \Omega$). Also, the integral of a strictly positive (resp. negative) function over a 
region of positive measure is strictly positive (resp. negative). From this, it should be easy to see that an integral over a variable region of integration is bounded above by the integral over the maximal region on which the integrand is positive.

Answer (score -1):

If you take, say, a rectangle oriented clockwise with vertices $[0,0]$, $[0,1]$, $[X,1]$, $[X,0]$ you can make the integral arbitrarily large.
Or was there an assumption on the orientation of the curve?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention, but the curve should be oriented positively.